# Offline and online application using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

brief history of my project:
2 versions of application, one running in windows form, another running in the web using asp.net

current task: to revamp the project to use asp.net mvc 4 to use only one version of code base.
 In final product, there will no more windows form; but only the asp.net mvc. this is with regards with short development timeline.

concern:
 my concern is for offline users. 
 maybe i can host the asp.net mvc4 offline using localhost and sql lite. 
 When offline users click on check update, there will be able to get the latest version of asp.net mvc 4 ?

any other better solution that is feasible ? i prefer the architecture fits the vb.net

Comment: Deploying MVC app with SqlLite in localhost will be quite a challenge in term of maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you take a look at SPA. That kind of projects, by nature, can work in online and offline mode. One thing to take into account is the ammount of data that the offline mode should handle (most SPAs are using the local storage for offline use, which is a little small)
By looking at this site you will find a lot of resourses on SPA.
http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/

Answer (score 0):

Deploying MVC app with Sqlite in localhost will be quite a challenge in term of maintenance. Maybe you can develop HTML + jQuery solution which can run locally on client system and make use of client cache to hold the temp data. Also it can interact with live app by making ajax calls.